# Evaluate if cell value is part of named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range ("Categories") which contains for example Fruits, Vegetables, Sodas etc. Then I have 3 other named ranges for each of the entries in Categories. So for example I would have apples, oranges, grapes and name that range "Fruits". Now I would like to evaluate a long list of entries for whether they are part of each of the Categories. So for instance I want to evaluate whether CoCa-Cola is part of the Fruits named range. For same reason I couldn't make this work when using simple formulas in Excel. I have tried using the Function below but this didn't work either. I would appreciate if someone can help.

```
    Function RangeInCell(rngCellToCheck As Range, rngRangeToCheckWith As Range) As Boolean

        On Error Resume Next
        RangeInCell = Not Application.Intersect(rngCellToCheck, rngRangeToCheckWith) Is Nothing
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo -1: On Error GoTo 0

    End Function
```

Comment: Are you looking to just check if the item exists, or are you wanting to return the category name for the match?

Comment: Your function is looking for an intersection of two range objects, it's not doing anything about the *values*. I'd suggest `IFERROR(MATCH("coca-cola", Fruits, 0),False)`.

Comment: Glitch_Doctor: No unfortunately that didn't work. However, I have to reference both the Apple and Fruits to other cells. And I have to enter the ISNUMBER formula in a different worksheet from where the actual named ranges is. I don't know if this is somehow the reason for my problem.

Comment: Or: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("coca-cola",Fruits,0)),FALSE,TRUE)`

Comment: The named range can be accessed okay throughout the workbook so as long as it is in the same file you should be fine... We might need a sample of how your data is laid out with a before / after example if you could please? the thing about going through the categories list to look through each named range can bring us in to nasty territory of volatile formulas so i want to be sure I can't tackle this another way first.

Comment: A simple countif? =COUNTIF(Fruits,"coca cola")>0

Answer (score 0):

As long as your ranges are qualified properly, this should work between multiple workbooks, I think. Untested.

```
Function RangeInCell(rngCellToCheck As Range, rngRangeToCheckWith As Range) As Boolean

    Dim ret as Variant
    ret = Application.Match(rngCellToCheck, rngRangeToCheckWith, 0)

    RangeInCell = (Not IsError(ret))

End Function
```

As worksheet functions, I think this should also do it (tested in a single sheet/workbook)

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("coca-cola",Fruits,0)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

[image]